# Discord.js creating responsive command using .awaitMessages

Tags: discord.js

Basically I want to make a  command using .awaitMessages,
I want to store answers in `MessageEmbeds`

If bot asks me for the title it should store it in `.setTitle(title)`
If bot asks me for description it should store it in `.setDescription(description)`.

Comment: Please elaborate on your problem. What do you mean, Title and Description? Can you show some code?

Comment: You can use `.awaitMessages` for this. You can read more about it here: 
(https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#await-messages)

Comment: @Daniel Reynolds everything is  explained up there, if i had code i wouldnt be here

Comment: @Pepe_Worm ill try to do something with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in a comment, you should use [`TextChannel.awaitMessages()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=awaitMessages): every time you want to ask something you'll need to wait for the message from that user and then move to the next thing until you have all you need.
You can do everything with the `Promise.then()` method, but I find it way easier to just use async functions for that

You'll need to do something like this:

```js
// Let's say that message is the message with the command
async function getInfo(message) {
  // We'll use this if the user doesn't reply
  let timedOut = false

  // Save channel and author so that it's easier to write
  const { channel, author } = message

  // Define a filter function that will accept only messages from this author
  const isFromAuthor = m => m.author.id == author.id

  const options = {
    max: 1,
    time: 60 * 1000 // max time to wait (in ms)
  }

  // First question
  await channel.send('Title?')
  // await for the first response
  const firstColl = await channel.awaitMessages(isFromAuthor, options)

  // Check that there's at least one message
  if (firstColl.size > 0) {
    const title = firstColl.first().content

    await channel.send('Description?')
    const secondColl = await channel.awaitMessages(isFromAuthor, options)

    if (secondColl.size > 0) {
      const description = secondColl.first().content

      // You have everything you need, you can now send your embed
      let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed({
        title,
        description
      })

      channel.send(embed)
    } else timedOut = true
  } else timedOut = true

  if (timedOut)
    channel.send('Command canceled (timed out)')
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed, thanks mate

Comment: Happy to hear that, you're welcome :)